# 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Tags: swift

Alright, so just to start off, heres my code:

```
import UIKit
import ForecastIO

class Weather {
    var temp: Float
    var condition: String
    var wind: Float
    var precip: Float

    init() {
        DarkSkyClient(apiKey: "<api key>").getForecast(latitude: Utils().getLat(), longitude: Utils().getLong()) { result in

            switch result {
            case .success(let currentForecast, _):

                self.temp = (currentForecast.currently?.temperature)!
                self.condition = (currentForecast.currently?.summary)!
                self.wind = (currentForecast.currently?.windSpeed)!
                self.precip = (currentForecast.currently?.precipitationProbability)!

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

            }

        }

    }

}
```

So my error comes up because I'm trying to initialize temp inside of the API call. I know this isn't the most reliable way of doing it but I'm trying to first get it to work.

The first error is:

> 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

on the line `DarkSkyClient(apiKey: "").getForecast(latitude: Utils().getLat(), longitude: Utils().getLong()) { result in`

My second error:

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

on the second to last `}`

Now, obviously I'm not initializing right. I can't find the proper way to do what my end goal is though. Maybe I'm doing this entirely wrong?

Comment: An object can't asynchronously initialize itself.  Your API call should be called by another object that should call an initializer for your `Weather` class and pass in the values it gets from the API.

Comment: @dan I understand that part, I just don't understand what the proper way to do this is, with another object. (Also, thanks for helping)

Comment: You could declare your member variables as Optionals

Comment: @odlund I tried this but I get an unexpected nil.

Comment: Give all of the properties some default value before doing the async code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd hazard to guess that your are running into a concurrency problem. You are probably trying to access your object's properties before the asynchronous call to the DarkSkyClient returns (my apologies in advance if I got this wrong). i.e., the order of events is...

1. Weather object is initialized, setting temp to 0
2. Call to DarkSkyClient begins, runs in the background
3. Read temp variable - hey, it's 0!
4. Call to DarkSkyClient completes, sets the temp to the value you really wanted. Bad

So what you really need to do is switch to an inversion of control pattern:

```
class Weather {
    var temp: Float
    var condition: String
    var wind: Float
    var precip: Float

    init(forecast: Forecast) {
        temp = (forecast.currently?.temperature)!
        condition = (forecast.currently?.summary)!
        wind = (forecast.currently?.windSpeed)!
        precip = (forecast.currently?.precipitationProbability)!
    }

    static func getWeather() {
        DarkSkyClient(apiKey: "<api key>").getForecast(latitude: Utils().getLat(), longitude: Utils().getLong()) { result in

            switch result {
            case .success(let currentForecast, _):
                let weather = Weather(forecast: currentForecast)
                // Display the weather somewhere
                doSomethingWith(weather: weather)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

If you're not familiar with developing with asynchronous APIs it's worth your while to read up on the subject; it can be very tricky (sadly, I don't have any recommendations for a good primer).
Hope this helps!

Comment: Why with even optional init() cause the same problem?

Comment: Please explain to me how he can he have a concurrency problem when the code doesn't even compile?

Answer (score 39):

For me, it's because I didn't call `super.init()` in the initializer.

```
class AnObject: NSObject {
    override init() {
//        super.init()

        let _: ()-> (Void) = {
            print(String(describing: self))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works because you, I, and probably the other 16 up-voters of your answer have a slight variation on the situation: Our problem classes inherit from NSObject.

Answer (score 15):

You have two options, declare the properties as optionals, or initialize them with a default value (this means they will be non-optionals)

```
var temp: Float?
var condition: String?
var wind: Float?
var precip: Float?
```

or

```
var temp: Float=0
var condition: String=""
var wind: Float=0
var precip: Float=0
```

Comment: In the second option, change all of the `0` to `0.0` and you can remove all of the explicit type declarations.

Comment: @rmaddy That would make them `Double`s (which may or may not be desired)

Comment: @Hamish True. That did occur to me after posting my comment. :)

Comment: The issue with this is when the app runs, if I do anything with it using option 1, I get unexpected nil. If I use option 2, I just get the values I put in as a placeholder but not the actual APIs response value. And 0.0 works as a Float (as well as a double, which it defaults to if you don't explicitly put `Float:`

Comment: You need to reload the presentation of the data where you are using it, remember that is an async call

Comment: @omarzl how would I do that?