# How to initialize an object which assigns to self in a closure in its init()?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Database wrapper class around a Firebase database and I want to cache the Firebase snapshot, hence I have this code:

```
@objc final class Database : NSObject
{
    var spamRef: FIRDatabaseReference!  = nil
    var snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot?       = nil

    override init()
    {
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
        FIRApp.configure()
        spamRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "spam_list")
        _ = spamRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (theSnapshot) in
            self.snapshot = theSnapshot
            ...
```

Which results in a 'self captured by a closure before all members were initialized'.

I know what the error means, and what the cause is; my question is what is an elegant solution to fix it.

If I move the closure out of the init() and into a separate function that gets called after init has completed, then that separate function still needs to get called.
If its called explicitly by the code that creates the Database object then I don't consider that a good solution - the calling code now has exposure to the internals of the implementation and responsibility that this function needs to be called.

The init() method of course can't call this method directly, but it could schedule the function to be called after a micro-second delay (so the run loop will complete and the init() will have completed before the new function is called).
But this seems clunky.

What's an elegant solution?

Comment: Call `super.init()` first?

Comment: You can't have an async call in `init()`.  Use optionals or a lazy var to access the contents of the snapshot.  See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42403488/2415822

Comment: @JAL I don't want to use lazy as I want the snapshot to be initialized and ready to use after app launch as its a very large dataset and could take several seconds, so when its accessed its immediatey available and thus can be accessed synchonously by the calling code.

Comment: @dan. That works, thanks. But how does calling super.init() first actually solve the issue?