# Initialized variable: 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having issues with initialization of a custom class. I need to set up an observer on some data when the class is initialized which updates properties. Initially, the properties can be empty and that is how I set them at initiation. However, Xcode still throws the "'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized" error. Here is a shortened version of the code.

```
class Foo {
    init() {
        self.usersRef = ref.child("users")
        self.usersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // snapshot error checking
            // users is [String]

            self.users = users
        })
    }

    private var usersRef: DatabaseReference
    private(set) var users: [String] = []

}
```

I have also tried

```
class Foo {
    init() {
        self.users = [String]()
        self.usersRef = ref.child("users")
        self.usersRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // snapshot error checking
            // users is [String]

            self.users = users
        })
    }

    private var usersRef: DatabaseReference
    private(set) var users: [String]

}
```

to ensure initialization prior to the callback.

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403488/self-captured-by-a-closure-before-all-members-were-initialized) it seemed I only needed to give the properties initial values, but this does not seem to be the case. I would prefer not to have to call another function to set up these handlers after initialization.

Thank you for an help

Comment: where do you initialize `usersRef` variable?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Thank you, I missed that in the question, fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this block

```
 { [unowned self] (snapshot) in
            // snapshot error checking
            // users is [String]

            self.users = users
        })
```

or

```
{ [weak self] (snapshot) in
            // snapshot error checking
            // users is [String]

            self?.users = users
        })
```

Comment: I had seen the ```[unowned self]``` while searching for a solution, but i'm not fully understanding its purpose. From what I understand it is creating a weak reference? Will this create other possible issues I should look out for in error checking?

Comment: @JustinOroz I have not faced huge problems while using those wrappers

Comment: Thank you, it compiles fine, and I can't see any issues arising from a weaker reference, so this works great! I'll mark it as accepted, thank you.

Comment: Basically a strong self will add to the retain count, thus it will always point to itself while it exists, creating a retain-cycle. That's why you want(ed) a weak reference