# How to pass a local function to another object during init?

Tags: swift

How to pass a local function to another object during init?

I did the below, but got `'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized`

```
class ContextViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    let drawViewWrapper: ContentView
    
    init(drawView: CustomDrawView) {
        self.drawViewWrapper = ContentView(
            drawView: drawView,
            dismiss: { self.dismiss(animated: true) }) // Error here
        super.init(rootView: self.drawViewWrapper)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The answer in ['self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42403488/3286489) doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to remove `dismiss` parameter from your `ContentView`'s initializer and set it after calling `super.init(rootView: self.drawViewWrapper)`.

Answer (score 0):

if it's an option for you I'd suggest making the `dismiss` block not part of the init but rather an optional var on the ContentView.

My solution would look kind of like:

`ContentView`

```
class ContentView: UIView {
    var dismiss: (() -> Void)?
    
    init(drawView: UIView) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    ...
}
```

You could also indicate the dismiss block will always be there by replacing the `?` with an `!` (`var dismiss: (() -> Void)!`) so you don't have to unwrap it when calling but I wouldn't suggest that as it's not compile time safe and so not what you really want.

`ContextViewController`

```
class ContextViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    let drawViewWrapper: ContentView
    
    lazy var selfDismiss: () -> Void = { [unowned self] in
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    init(drawView: CustomDrawView) {
        self.drawViewWrapper = ContentView(drawView: drawView)
        super.init(rootView: self.drawViewWrapper)
        self.drawViewWrapper.dismiss = selfDismiss
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your property `drawViewWrapper` seems to be useless here since you can access it later with `self.rootView` and second, you should use `[unowned self]` to avoid capturing 'self' and creating a weak reference to it instead (and then avoid a retain-cycle).

So I would do something like this instead:

```
class ContextViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
    
    init(drawView: CustomDrawView) {
        let drawViewWrapper = ContentView(
            drawView: drawView,
            dismiss: { [unowned self] in
                self.dismiss(animated: true)
            })
        super.init(rootView: drawViewWrapper)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And then if you need to access it later, you can simply use `self.rootView`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to call `super.init()` before:

```
class ContextViewController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    let drawViewWrapper: ContentView?
    
    init(drawView: CustomDrawView) {
        super.init(rootView: self.drawViewWrapper)
        self.drawViewWrapper = ContentView(
            drawView: drawView,
            dismiss: { self.dismiss(animated: true) })
    }

}
```

Comment: There will be 3 errors with the above `Constant 'self.drawViewWrapper' used before being initialized`, `Property 'self.drawViewWrapper' not initialized at super.init call` and  `Immutable value 'self.drawViewWrapper' may only be initialized once`

Comment: Do note in the `super.init`, I'm supplying the `self.drawViewWrapper`. Hence initialize it after the init is not permitted

Comment: What if you make `drawViewWrapper` optional?